# Rails form with a subset of has_many :through checkboxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many-through

I have a fairly straightforward application for assigning `Abilities` to `Users`, using `Permissions` as a join table. I've included the model definitions below.

However, `Abilities` also belong to a `Client`. The form for adding Abilities to a User contains only the Abilities **for a specific Client**.

As the form only returns *checked* ability_ids for that client, if I simply use

```
@user.update(params[:user].permit({:ability_ids => []}))
```

with form

```
= simple_form_for(@user, url: user_permissions_path, method: :patch do |f|
  = f.hidden_field :client_id, value: @client.id, name: :client_id
  = f.association :abilities, as: :check_boxes, collection: @client.abilities
```

Then *all permissions for all other client applications are deleted for that user*. This is the controller update code I'm using currently, but i'm pretty confident there's a more 'Rails way' to do this.

```
# permissions_controller#update

# Filter empty elements
update_abilities  = params[:user][:ability_ids].reject { |c| c.empty? }

# Get list of current ability ids
current_abilities = @user.abilities.for_client(@client).pluck(:id).collect{ |i| i.to_s }

abilities_for_deletion = @user.permissions.where(ability_id: current_abilities - update_abilities)
abilities_for_deletion.delete_all unless abilities_for_deletion.empty?

abilities_for_addition = Ability.find(update_abilities - current_abilities)
@user.abilities.push(abilities_for_addition)
```

---

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :permissions, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :abilities, through: :permissions do
    def for_client(client)
      where('abilities.client_id' => client.id)
    end
  end
end

class Permission < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :ability
  belongs_to :user
end


class Ability < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :permissions, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :client
end
```

I ask because I now need to modify user groups via the same form, which also belong to a specific client, and would require large duplication of this update code.

Thanks.

Comment: I ran into a nearly identical situation with my models and came up with the same solution you did.  I would be interested to see another (more modular) approach.